Relationship between unitaries generated by a Hamiltonian and its negative sign
Consider two unitary operations $U_1$ and $U_2$ defined by:
$\partial_t U_1 = -iH_1U_1$ and $\partial_t U_2 = iH_1U_2$
Here, $U_1$ is generated by $H_1$ and $U_2$ is generated by $-H_1$, with the possibility that both $H_1$ and $H_2$ are time-dependent.
Is it true that $U_1^\dagger(t) = U_2(t)$ at any time $t$?
My guess is no. My reasoning is that when we express $U_1$ perturbatively in terms of $H_1$, using the Dyson series, it results in a sum of terms dependent on $H_1^k$. Therefore, changing the sign of $H_1$ only affects the odd-order terms, while the even-order terms, $H_1^k$ for even $k$, remain unchanged. This implies that $U_1^\dagger(t) \neq U_2(t)$. Is this intuition correct?
Also, in this situation of $H_1$ and $-H_1$, what can be say about $U_1$ and $U_2$?

maybe $U_1^*=U_2$ of $H$ is real but $^\dagger$ implies a change in the ordering of $H$ and $U$ so it’s not so simple as just eyeballing it.

Short answer: Your guess is correct, for general time-dependent Hamiltonians $U_1^\dagger(t)\neq U_2(t)$ and there is usually no relation between these two (we will give two simple counterexamples below).
The problem is that time-dependent Hamiltonians need not commute with themselves at different times.

First, a quick sanity check that in the commutative case $U_1^\dagger$ and $U_2$ do indeed coincide: if $[H(t),H(t')]=0$ for all $t\neq t'$, then
$$
U_1^\dagger(t)=\Big(e^{\int_0^t-iH_1(t)\,dt}\Big)^\dagger=e^{\int_0^t(-iH_1(t))^\dagger\,dt}=e^{\int_0^tiH_1(t)\,dt}=U_2(t)\,.
$$
Without the commutation condition, however, this is wrong – already for the simple case of piecewise-constant Hamiltonians. For this consider $H:[0,2]\to i\mathfrak u(2)$ defined via
$$
H(t):=\begin{cases}
Z&t\in[0,\frac\pi2]\\
X&t\in(\frac\pi2,\pi]
\end{cases}\tag1
$$
(with $X:=\sigma_x$, $Z:=\sigma_z$ the usual Pauli matrices).
Obviously,
$
U_1(\pi)=e^{-i\frac\pi2X}e^{-i\frac\pi2Z}
$
and
$
U_2(\pi)=e^{i\frac\pi2X}e^{i\frac\pi2Z}
$ meaning
$$
U_1^\dagger(\pi)=e^{i\frac\pi2Z}e^{i\frac\pi2X}=\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1\\1&0
\end{pmatrix}\neq \begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\-1&0
\end{pmatrix}=e^{i\frac\pi2X}e^{i\frac\pi2Z}=U_2(\pi)\,.
$$
At first glance it seems like there is at least some relation between $U_1^\dagger$ and $U_2$, e.g., in terms of eigenvalues or similar.
That, however, is an artifact of our $H(t)$ in (1) taking only two values: if we choose anything slightly more complicated such as
$$
H(t):=\begin{cases}
Z&t\in[0,\frac\pi4]\\
Y&t\in(\frac\pi4,\frac\pi2]\\
X&t\in(\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}4]
\end{cases},
$$
then
$$U_1^\dagger(\tfrac{3\pi}4)=e^{i\frac\pi4Z}e^{i\frac\pi4Y}e^{i\frac\pi4X}=
\frac i{\sqrt2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has eigenvalues $\pm i$
while
$$U_2(\tfrac{3\pi}4)=e^{i\frac\pi4X}e^{i\frac\pi4Y}e^{i\frac\pi4Z}=\frac 1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}
 1& 1 \\
 -1& 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has eigenvalues $\frac{1\pm i}{\sqrt2}$.
